# how to alias git checkout && git stash apply

Tags: git, git-commit, git-stash

So I have two branches master and formtest

I have an [alias] "git switch" that lets me stash any works in progress and checkout another branch.

"git switch"

```
switch = !git stash && git checkout
```

Now I want to create an [alias]

"git switchback"

```
switchback = ???
```

when run it I want it to say

switch to this branch "formtest"

and then run stash apply

to unstash the last WIP done and return things back before I first ran "git switch"

Comment: That (legit) is hot sex with a super model! I would like to see it as a ruby gem (just for nerd's sake). I am still curious as to the actual answer to my initial question tho' just want more raw control over my git write now.

Comment: There are a lot of things you might need to consider in your implementation. For example, I'm not sure why you have the `!` before `git stash`, because presumably you'd want to switch to the new branch only if the `git stash` was successful. But what if there wasn't anything to stash? You should check that beforehand. Conversely, in the `switchback` command you'd have to remember somewhere what the name of the branch you want to switch back to was, and then unstash the stashsed changes, but only if there had been anything to stash in the first place. Legit takes care of all this for you. :)

Comment: [foreword] been using the github app for awhile and after using git for a few years. found the app to be fantastic in a few places...teaching others what I've discovered...some (including my self) want to know how to do these things on CLI. WITHOUT a third part tool. My students are ruby coders. So while legit is great...unless she's written in ruby...she's only a one night stand for what I need for my students. ;)

Comment: @GregHewgill, you should make an answer from your great comment about Legit

Comment: @GregHewgill's link does not go to the correct project page. It should most likely be updated to: https://frostming.github.io/legit/

Comment: @maurelian: Thanks for the update, I've deleted my original comment which now links to a dead domain. Original comment with fixed link: "It sounds like you're looking for [Legit](https://frostming.github.io/legit/), which is a set of enhanced Git commands including a `git switch` with automatic stash/unstash."

Comment: Does this even work, I thought `git switch` was a real git subcommand and those cannot be overwritten/superseded by an alias?

Answer (score 0):

To switch back to the branch you worked on before

```
git checkout - && git stash apply
```

The `-` will work similar to `-` in `cd -` e.g. switch back to the last branch(location) you used.

---

**But** beware that this will `checkout` the wrong branch if you happen to `checkout` another branch in between.

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout $(git log --format=%B -n 1 stash@{0} | grep -oP '(?<=^WIP on )[^(:][^:]*' || git rev-parse stash@{0}^)
```

This will parse the latest stash commit message that contains the branch name it was made on. If there were no branch (detached HEAD), it will checkout the parent commit of the stash.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a shell function and immediately invoke it:

```
git config --global alias.switchback 'f() { git checkout "$1" && git stash apply; }; f'
```

Then call:

```
git switchback master # switch to master and apply stash
git switchback - # switch to previous branch and apply stash
```

You can make the alias default to `-` (previous branch) quite easily:

```
git config --global alias.switchback 'f() { git checkout "${1:--}" && git stash apply; }; f'
```

then `git switchback` will go to the previous branch and apply the stash, but you can still run `git switchback branchname` to switch to a different branch.